# Why doesn't my regression line go through the point cloud?

Tags: regression

I created a scatterplot from my data set.

```
reg1 <- lm(CTonProzkorrRC~CTonProzkorr, data = RC_korrigiert_DF1) 
summary(reg1)
with(RC_korrigiert_DF1,plot(RC_korrigiert_DF1$CTonProzkorrRC,
RC_korrigiert_DF1$CTonProzkorr,
ylab = "CN-Analyser %C", xlab = "RC-Analyser %C"))
abline(reg1)
```

[image: scatterplot with abline through the nothing]

The abline does not go through the cloud of points. From eye-view I would assume that the abline should go through the cloud because it consists of comparatively many values.

What is the reason for the position of the regression-line?

Comment: You switched the X and Y coordinates.

Comment: one way to mitigate these kinds of errors is to eschew relying on argument order and give argument names

Comment: LOL... am I supposed to delete this post now? I feel very stupid.